# Not getting the output for assigned numbers to variable with commas using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the numbers with commas but am not getting any result or output.

Am I doing it the correct way??

Below is the code which I am using :

```
function expense() {
  var total2 = 23,09,567;
  var total3 = 45,890;
  var total4 = 67,890;
  var total5 = 10,78,893;
  var total6 = 4,890;

  var total = parseFloat(total2.replace(/,/g,''))+parseFloat(total3.replace(/,/g,''))+parseFloat(total4.replace(/,/g,''))+parseFloat(total5.replace(/,/g,''))+parseFloat(total6.replace(/,/g,'')));

  alert(total);
  if(!isNaN(total))
  {
    document.getElementById("total").value=total;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the sum? or just the numbers concatinated?

Answer (score 1):

A comma (`,`) inside of a `var` declaration is used to seperate declarations, e.g.:

```
  var a = 1, b = 2;
```

equals:

```
 var a = 1;
 var b = 2;
```

That means that this line:

```
 var total2 = 23,09,567;
```

equals:

```
  var total2 = 23;
  var 09 = ?;
  var 567 = ?;
```

As this makes little sense, JavaScript throws a Syntax error which you can see in your console.

> [I] am not getting any result or output.

Wrong. Go to your browsers developer console to see the output (an error).

To resolve the issue you want to use String literals (`"23,09,567"`) instead as they got a `.replace` method.

Comment: i want numeric values not string literals

Answer (score 1):

`var total2 = 23,09,567;` is creating our first problem. `23,09,567` isn't a valid integer/float so it should be either of the following:

```
var option1 = 2309567;
var option2 = 23.09567;
var option3 = 2309.567;
var option4 = '23,09,567';
```

Adding to that comes the fact that in order to declare a float, you use `.` instead of `,`. So as an example you would declare it like `var example = 123.456;`

Furthermore, a float can only have 1 dot so `var total2 = 23.09.567;` won't work but either of these will:

```
var option1 = 2309.567;
var option2 = 23.09567;
```

Lastly, the `.replace(/,/g,'')` works only for `Strings` and not for integers/floats, but if you declare your variables as correct integers/floats you don't even need the `.replace`

Answer (score 0):

`replace` is a string-function, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Change your inputs to strings, e.g.

```
var total2 = '23,09,567';
```